# Broken Masyu: Quartered

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

Below is an 8x8 Masyu puzzle (rules can be found [here](http://www.nikoli.com/en/puzzles/masyu/rule.html)), but the puzzle has been broken into four pieces! Can you put the pieces back together to make a proper Masyu puzzle with a unique solution? (The pieces can be rotated, and swapped, but they cannot be flipped. The red piece cannot be rotated, but can be swapped. This just reduces 4 solutions (trivial rotations of each other) down to a single one.)

[image]

Comment: Link to rules appears broken. FWIW, use http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd label the 4 subgrids and the circles first.
[image: My labeling]
(Apparently 24px font size isn't clear(big?) enough here. Oh well.)

> Start from Subgrid A. A1 and A3 can't be a corner tile due to basic Masyu rules. If tile 'below' A5 is a corner, that means A4 and A5 are joined together, and both turn 'upwards', wrapping A2 in a dead end. Contradiction. So tile 'right of' A2 is a corner tile, exactly which is not known yet. Now we can draw some lines on Subgrid A.
> [image: Green Lines are Walls]
> Now to Subgrid B. Line cannot go 'left' from B2, else either B1 or B3 is cornered. So we can start B with:
> [image: First lines for B] 
> That means B cannot go 'left of' A in any way:
> [image: Putting B1 into known path from A3 leaves B3 cornered]
> Now to Subgrid C. Line cannot go 'down' from C1, else C2 is adjacent to no turns. So we can start C with:
> [image: First lines for C]
> That means C cannot go 'left of' A in any way:
> [image: C1's known line rams into somewhere between A1,A2 and A4,A5]
> That leaves A's 'left' joined to Subgrid D. Putting Subgrid A as Upper Left above Subgrid D would force D2 and D3 in a loop of their own:
> [image: A above D on left] 
> A right of D as Upper Right leaves no valid solution for D3:
> [image: A right of D on top] 
> A below D as Lower Right means Line has to go through D3 and D2 first, leaving D1 in a dead end:
> [image: A below D on right]
> And with that we now know A is lower left corner, and D is lower right. With this in mind we can draw some lines onto D:
> [image: Finally two subgrids in their places]
> If we now put C above D, because C1's known line cannot run into D, it needs to run left into B, making B2's known line going down into A:
> [image: You wanna corner B1,B3 or seal out A3?] 
> Whichever way C1's other line goes causes contradiction. So C is upper left, B is upper right. Running C1's known line rightward leads to this:
> [image: Also notice C2,C3,C4 - at least one among them is deadended]
> With B2 and D1 forming a loop of their own, contradiction. So C1's known line has to go down. Now we can add more lines.
> [image: Which orientation should B be at?]
> Running B1's known line leftward leads to this:
> [image: One last bummer]
> Either putting C2 and C3 into a loop of their own or putting either C2 or C3 into a dead end. Contradiction. So B1's known line goes downward.
> [image: The grid finally complete]
> Now we can fill out the remaining lines to get the answer loop.
> [image: Answer]